Horror movie set in the Southern US involving a woman in hospital and her psychic son
I remember watching this movie on cable around 2008 to 2010. The movie was probably less than five years old when I saw it.
It took place in the Southern US--I'm thinking Bayou Country--but was centered on a hospital. Beautiful, young female lead (doctor?) with handsome, young male (also doctor?) in tow.
There was a young man, heavyset with a crew cut or shaved head, and kind of creepy. He didn't speak much, big and dumb. His heavyset mother was in a hospital bed. She spoke in a southern drawl, also creepy. Eventually, she died. The son unleashes psychic powers on the hospital. The lights went out and, I assume because I can't remember, many people died horribly. I also assume that the two doctors somehow survived.
In the final scene, the young man got into his truck and the camera panned left or pulls out, to reveal what we must assume is the spirit of his dead mother sitting beside him.
It ain't much, but that's all I can remember. A dark movie set in a creepy bayou with a mother and her psychic son and the ending with a truck. For some reason, I thought the title was The Manitou, which is a totally different movie from the mid-seventies, set in a brightly lit New York City. So, I don't know how I came up with that title.

Somewhat reminiscent of THE SENDER but that film was from 1982. https://www.popmatters.com/the-sender-delivers-psychic-horror-2495483723.html
